# Гриб Ксилярия (ксилярия) длинноногая – выбор написания

Tags: кавычки, названия

«Гриб Ксилярия длинноногая» или «гриб ксилярия длинноногая». Что выбрать?

Answer (score 0):

**Гриб ксилярия длинноногая**
Это ж не имя конкретного гриба. Пишется со строчной, как *дерево берёза* или *человек разумный*.

Comment: Официальные названия растений пишутся с прописной буквы https://wikigrib.ru/ksilyariya-dlinnonogaya/

Comment: @Sharon я не находил такой информации в справочниках. Что касается вашей ссылки, то есть немало других ссылок, где ксилярия пишется со строчной, например: gribowiki.ru/inedible/ksilyariya-dlinnonogaya.html Также вот скриншот из определителя грибов, где родо-видовое название "дубовик крапчатый" написано со строчной. i.imgur.com/xWbKKe5.png Грамота указывает, что *в специальной литературе* используется прописная буква, но разве определитель — не специальная литература? new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=294942

Comment: Так автор вопроса выбрал прописную букву, вероятно, он имел в виду официальное название. В случае сомнения можно уточнить или привести оба варианта (официальное и обычное название).

Comment: @Sharon что такое "официальное название" и почему оно пишется с заглавной? Укажите, пожалуйста, соответствующие пункты в справочниках.

Comment: У Розенталя это называется  специальной литературой. http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=26#pp26

Comment: @Sharon у него речь про сорта. Он пишет "малина Мальборо", но не "ягода Малина". Тогда уж следует писать "гриб ксилярия Длинноногая". И то вряд ли, потому что "длинноногая" — это наименование вида, а сорт по систематике стоит ниже вида (если точнее, он вообще вне систематики).

Comment: Вполне возможно, если говорить о Розентале. Но это общий образец записи видовых названий  в биологии (прописная буква, определение после определяемого слова). Так и человека можно записать, а не только гриб. Семейство: Гоминиды. Род: Человек (Люди). Вид: Человек разумный. Или вы против? :))

Comment: @Sharon может быть. Но мне аргументов недостаточно, поэтому ответ менять не стану.

Comment: Да разве я вас прошу об этом? :)) Мы же просто разговариваем, а ответ вы оформляете, как считаете нужным.  А аргументов у меня больше нет, увы...